# Excel VBA - fill in diff timezone times based on daylight savings date

Tags: excel, vba

Me again! CtznKane if youre still there, little help?

I set up the function you suggested, but for some reason it does not do what it is supposed to. it doesn't return an error, just seems to always return a false value even where it should return true.

```
Public Function isdaydat(ByVal datval As Date) As Boolean

Select Case True
    Case datval > CDate("3/9/2008") And datval < CDate("11/1/2008")
    isdaydat = True
    Case Else
    isdaydat = False

   End Select

End Function
```

here is how I call it in the texbox subroutine to show reg or daylight int he dayconf textbox

```
fixdat = CDate(Me.dtefrm.Value)
Me.dtefrm.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(fixdat, "mm/dd/yyy")

isvaldst = isdaydat(Me.dtefrm.Value)

If isvaldat = True Then
    Me.dayconf.Value = "Daylight"
    Else
    Me.dayconf.Value = "Regular"
End If
```

Comment: I'd recommend you call your function using `isvaldat = isdaydat(fixdat)` because `fixdat` appears to be a `Date` variable while `Me.dtefrm.Value` will be a string, but your function seems to work for me irrespective of whether you pass a date or a string (e.g. `isdaydat("04/01/2008")` returns `True` if I change my settings to be in a "mm/dd/yyyy" date format).  Step through the code and see what the value of `datval` is when you are inside the function.

Comment: DOH!!!  Typo.  (I originally only looked at the function.)  `isvaldat` and `isvaldst` are different variables, and you never assign a value to `isvaldat`.  Put `Option Explicit` as the first line of every module so that you are forced to declare your variables.  Then you are less likely to use the wrong variable names.

Comment: Thanks!! How embarrassing.....thanks for the option explicit tip! you're right definitely seems to be a good practice.